# Using globs in grep statements

Tags: grep

If I grep a whole email address I'm able to turn up a result:

```
grep -ri "us-dbawsnplogging@company.com" *
manifest.yaml:        email: us-dbawsnplogging@company.com
```

However if I try to use a glob to get multiple email addresses it fails to return anything:

```
grep -ri "*@company.com" *
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`grep` uses regular expressions, not glob.

You should use:

```
grep -ri ".*@company\.com" *
```

where `.` stands for any character (then it have to be escaped to match a literal dot) and `.*` stands for 0 or more any character.

Comment: Thansk! That worked. I forgot that grep only uses regular expression, and forgot how to use them. Appreciate the info!